# Appending to list with "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'' error

Tags: python, for-loop, str-replace, data-cleaning

I want to iterate through a Result set, clean each item and then append to a list. I have a problem here:

When trying to append the list I get an error, namely 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. I tried to overcome with if pass, but I didnt work. Any ideas?

Here is the input:

```
I_Details = 
['27Dec2017']
['04Jan2018']
['22,000,000USD(fiat)']
['20,000,000USD']
['China,Japan,UnitedStates']
['ZIL']
['Utility-token']
['No']
[ETH,,]
[40%-MiningRewards,,30%-Company,Team,Agencies,,30%-Early&amp;CommunityContributors]
[(ZIL)]
[ETH,,,'return11.89x']
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Campaign_info_1 = list()
for Detail in I_Details:
  Campaign_info = Detail.contents
  Campaign_info = str(Campaign_info)
  if Campaign_info==None or Campaign_info=="": 
    pass 
  Campaign_info_1 = Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info) 
  print(Campaign_info)
```

Comment: This example input can't be interpreted without error.

Comment: Is the line `Campaign_info_1 = Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info) ` supposed to be inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is inside the for loop. Error persists.

Comment: `Campaign_info_1 = Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info) ` should be `Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info)` instead. Append mutates the original list, no need for reassignment. - Sorry if this doesn't fix, still can't run the code with that input.

Comment: @Deancoakley: Worked, thank you! :-)

Comment: @Carolin No problem. I've added an answer, would appreciate mark as best answer/upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Campaign_info_1 = Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info)` must be changed to `Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info)`. Append mutates the list, reassignment is not necessary and causes the error.

```
Campaign_info_1 = list()
for Detail in I_Details:
  Campaign_info = Detail.contents
  Campaign_info = str(Campaign_info)
  if Campaign_info==None or Campaign_info=="": 
    pass 
  Campaign_info_1.append(Campaign_info) 
  print(Campaign_info)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! :-)